# Timeouts in Ruby

Tags: ruby, timeout

I'm trying to make a math test.
I have written this code but console is not being friendly about it.
I'm trying to make it print out very impressive and not too slow if the user gets in right in 5 seconds. Here's what I wrote up.

```
puts "346*3?"
begin
  Timeout::timeout 5 do
    dans1 = gets.chomp
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  dans1 = nil
end

puts (dans1 || "Too slow!")

if dans1 == "1038"
  puts "Very impressive!"
else
  puts "Better luck next time..."
end
```

Ignore some of the `if`s and `end`s this is only a snippet the rest of my code works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting dans1 in the outer scope so it's only visible inside the block. I'd probably re-write the code like;

```
puts "346*3?"
dans1 = begin
  Timeout::timeout 5 do
    gets.chomp
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  "Too slow!"
end

puts dans1

if dans1 == "1038"
  puts "Very impressive!"
else
  puts "Better luck next time..."
end
```

If you are typing this straight into the console i.e. irb you will have a problem as gets will not work inside a code block that you are currently entering! What you need to do is save the code out to a file and load the file;

```
> load 'where-my-file-is/my-file.rb'
```

Then the code will be able to run through. Alternatively you could put it into a method;

```
def question
  puts "346*3?"
  dans1 = begin
    Timeout::timeout 5 do
      gets.chomp
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    "Too slow!"
  end

  puts (dans1)

  if dans1 == "1038"
    puts "Very impressive!"
  else
    puts "Better luck next time..."
  end
end
```

And call the method;

```
> question
```

Comment: This fixes the problem but does not explain at all what the problem was in the first place

Comment: @Max the question states about 'console is not being friendly' and I specifically answer that issue. The scope is an additional but the gets will not run in console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are declaring the `dans1` variable. As an exercise, try commenting out the `dans1 = nil` line in the rescue. Suddenly:

```
in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `dans1' for main:Object (NameError)
```

This happens because you first defined `dans1` here:

```
Timeout::timeout 5 do
  dans1 = gets.chomp
end
```

When you define a new variable inside a block, it is "block-local", meaning it does not exist outside of that block. So the block exits and then `puts` tries to read a nonexistent variable. The reason why your code worked in the first place was because the `dans1 = nil` line inside the rescue defines another `dans1` outside of the block that the `puts` can see. This definition occurs *whether or not the `rescue` runs*!!! This is one of the most confusing things about Ruby: the VM sees the `dans = nil` line and defines the variable even though the assignment isn't run.

To fix it, just define `dans1` before the block. Blocks can see outside of their scope, so it will reuse that `dans1` rather than defining a new block-local variable.

```
dans = nil
begin
  ...
```